# Trying to set a range for a random number in Java (JSP) but I'm unsure how to go about it

Tags: java, jsp, random, netbeans

So I've been tasked with making a program that produces random subtraction problems which, once you solve and submit, grades it and shows which you have gotten wrong and right. I, have already asked about that here regarding something similar before, so I already have the coding for this. My problem is within the details: the first number in the equation must always be either equal or greater than the second number. Here's what I've been trying to do so far:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>

<>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Subtraction Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
            int a, b, c, d, e, f, answer, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5;

            Random rand = new Random();
             a = rand.nextInt(1000); 
             b = rand.nextInt(1000);
             c = rand.nextInt(1000);
             d = rand.nextInt(1000);
             e = rand.nextInt(1000);
             f = rand.nextInt(1000);

             %>

    <form action="subResult.jsp">
        <%
          if ( a >= b) {
        %>

       1. <%= a %> - <%= b %>
        <% 
              request.setAttribute("a", a);
              request.setAttribute("b", b);
              %>
        = <input type="number" value="answer" name="answer"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="a" value="<%=a%>">
        <input type="hidden" name="b" value="<%=b%>">


       <% 
        } else { 
            a = ((1000 - b) + 1) + b;
        } 
        %>
```

Doing it this way causes "incompatible types: unexpected return value" to pop-up. How do I go about fixing that and, if I'm unable to, what should I do in-order to properly set this up?

EDIT1: So I removed the return and while it runs, it will occasionally just not display 1. (seemingly because it activates the condition of a not being greater or equal to b) on those certain instances.

Comment: Your problem is `return a;` It's not right to use `return` in a jsp

Comment: Your are on a JSP - you shouldn't be returning anything - just display it.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I've removed the return and edited my post appropriately with the developments that happened.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Not really, this doesn't really help with my current problem at the moment, though I do appreciate you formatting and making my code easier to read